# Getting response from SMTP server with PHP socket

Tags: php, sockets, stream, smtp

I am trying to connect on the couple of smtp hosts (yahoo,mail,gmail etc) using PHP, and check the response.

More precisely - does binded IP timeouts from specific host.

Note that, I am not checking is the main IP able to access SMTP host, I need to check are IP's binded on the interface.

I am able to connect to the socket and bind the IP , but I am getting no output.
This is my code:

```
<?php


function error() {
    $strerr = socket_last_error();
    $strmsg = socket_strerror($strerr);
    return $strmsg;
}

$ip = $argv[1];
$port = 25;
$hosts = array(
    "smtp.gmail.com",
    "mailin-01.mx.aol.com",
    "mx2.hotmail.com",
    "mta7.am0.yahoodns.net"
);
$host = "smtp.gmail.com";

   foreach ($hosts as $key) {
    if (!($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))) {
        echo error();
    }
    if (!socket_bind($sock, $ip)) {
        echo "Unable to bind to specific IP.";
    }

    //Check can we connect to the socket
    if (!socket_connect($sock, $key, $port)) {
        echo error() . "\n";
    }
    else {

        if (socket_recv($sock, $buf, 150, MSG_PEEK) === FALSE) {
            echo error() . "\n";
        }
        echo $buf;

    }
    socket_shutdown($sock);
    socket_close($sock);
}
```

I am running the script from cli.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
>             if (socket_recv($sock, $buf, 500, MSG_WAITALL) === FALSE) {
> ```

you are waiting for the server to send 500 bytes. If the welcome message from the server is shorter you still wait for 500 bytes because you've explicitly set `MSG_WAITALL`. But the server does not send any more data and does not close the connection (which would make the recv return too) because it is waiting for the client to continue with the SMTP dialog. This means you are stuck on this line.

Comment: Steffen Ullrich : Thanks for assistance! I've changed flag to  `MSG_PEEK` and was able to get some (kind) of the response. What troubles me, I am not sure do I receive full buffer, and that value can vary right? I don't need to communicate with SMTP, i need to see only the reply from the server for particular IP. I would appreciate if you take a look of updated code, and let me know is this correct way. Many thanks!

Comment: @fugitive: I'm not sure why you don't simply call `socket_recv` without any flags. Apart from that, to be sure that you got everything you need to have an understanding of the SMTP protocol and parse the data you receive accordingly. In the simplest and most common case you get exactly one line but there might be more lines. For more information refer to [the SMTP standard](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321).